# Docusign error TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT

Tags: docusignapi

This should be pretty simple. I have one composite template with 1 server template and 1 inline template with one signer. This is what the request looks like:

```
    {
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "c6dc72a6-51ae-47c3-a55a-7923a247f97c "
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Keaton",
                "email": "KathyKeaton1@outlook.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Doc1ForBigTest.docx",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the following document at 10:21 AM"
}
```

I want to use my copy of this particular document instead of the one in the template, but I get the TAB error mentioned above. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your document contain form fields?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had to make a call to ListDocuments to get the info on the server template and get the document id from that and use it. I was hoping there was some other way to do it.

Comment: @KathyLori : How to make a call to ListDocuments ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download your template and look at the documentId references.  It is likely that at some point the Web interface was used to update the document in the template, causing the new document to be added and the old one deleted.  This involved updating the tab documentId references to be updated to "2" or higher.  Now, when you substitute your document, you are specifying documentId="1" and DocuSign doesn't find a document with ID of "2" to put the tabs on.